# Error occurs on using the bin/hubot command

Tags: hubot

I am working with Hubot.I have made a myhubot directory in the C drive.Now when I am in the myhubot folder ,and I am using the command bin/hubot (as given in https://hubot.github.com/docs) I am getting the error ==>'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.When I am changing the directory to bin (that is, now I am in C:\myhubot\bin) and then using hubot command,the error given is ==>the system cannot find the path specified.I have checked my bin folder and it has two files(hubot and hubot.cmd).Please help in sorting out the problem.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and observe what and how to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). In case your question is about code, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

The "/docs" link you posted shows instructions for Unix/Linux.

And since you mentioned "C drive" I think you're trying to install Hubot on Windows. I think you're going to have a lot of problems trying to adapt those to Windows, so I recommend you use the Windows-specific deployment docs instead:

https://hubot.github.com/docs/deploying/windows/